# Access 2007 to Word, Outlook for 2-step Mail Merge

Tags: email, ms-word, ms-access-2007, outlook-2007, mailmerge

My VBA does the email merge wonderfully ... except, I have to click on "allow" - from Outlook - twice, for each email generated.  Is there a way to programatically get around this?

I am running Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1.  MS Office 2007. Computer is tightly locked down.  HTML format e-mail not supported - only plain text.  I do not have local admin rights.  I am not able to install additional add-ins or third party software, as I've found suggested numerous times.

Here is my working VBA:
Private Sub Send_Email_Merge()

```
Dim sDBPath As String

'Word variables
Dim oWD As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document

Dim RecCount As Long

'Sanity check on how many e-mails to be sent
RecCount = DLookup("[Email Count]", "qry_EmailMerge_Count")
Debug.Print RecCount

Set oWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWD.Visible = True

Set oDoc = oWD.Documents.Open("C:\MyTemp\MyDocs\MyEmailMerge.docx")

With oDoc.MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

    sDBPath = "C:\MyTemp\MydBs\My_Engine.accdb"
    .OpenDataSource Name:=sDBPath, _
       SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [qry_E Mail Merge]"


End With

oWD.Activate
oWD.Documents.Parent.Visible = True
oWD.Application.WindowState = 1
oWD.ActiveWindow.WindowState = 1

With oDoc.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToEmail
    .MailAddressFieldName = "Email Address"
    .MailSubject = "Your Action Required"
    .MailFormat = wdMailFormatPlainText
    .Execute
End With

oWD.Activate
oWD.Documents.Parent.Visible = True
oWD.Application.WindowState = 1
oWD.ActiveWindow.WindowState = 1

oWD.ActiveDocument.Close
oWD.Quit
Set oWD = Nothing
Set oDoc = Nothing
```

End Sub

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate directly from Access. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information. It describes all the required steps for automating Outlook from another applications.

Comment: Eugene, Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, your link takes me to a reference for Outlook 2000, slightly outdated for Outlook 2007.

Comment: Nothing has changed so far.